# The data is not received by method $.ajax success in ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

In ie9 the success method receives only by two parameters: textStatus and XMLHttpRequest. Data is always undefined. In all the other the other browsers the code works properly and all the 3 parameters are sent to success method. As a result I cannot process any of the ajax-requests after it is done. What can be the reason for it?

Here is the part of the method code:

```
SendAjax = function(async, type, act, t, datas)
{
    var datatype = 'html';
    if (type=='reload_weather' || type=='popup' || act == 'set_location')
        datatype = 'json';

    var result = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: '_ajax/',
        data: {act:act, type:type, datas:datas},
        type: "POST",
        dataType: datatype,
        cache: false,
        async: async,
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            printArray(arguments);
            /*
             {
                 "1": "success",
                 "2": {
                 "readyState": 4,
                 "status": 200,
                 "statusText": "OK"
                 }
             }
             */

            printArray(data);
            /*
                undefined
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a free tool like Fiddler2 (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what is requested and returned on a working and non-working browser.

Comment: Define "All the other browsers". Firefox? Chrome? Safari? Opera? IE 11? IE 10? IE 8? IE 7? Where have you actually tested it.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, Thank you! I have installed the app and see how it works. Still the ajax-request receives data and I can see the answer text in ie and in fiddle. There is what I need. But how can I procees it in code and why don't it appear in success method?

Comment: @Quentin, from the listed browsers, I haven't tried only ie7,8.
Here is the answer from ie10:

'arguments:{
"0": {
    "html": "...",
    "title": "My Tourists"
},
"1":"success",
"2": {
    "readyState": 4,"responseText": "{"..."}","status": 200,"statusText": "OK"}}'

Comment: async is a boolean and it's default is true, contentType is what YOU are sending to the server and dataType is what you expect back.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by adding this line to php-file, that receives the request:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```